# Why do I need parenthesis in the condition part of a PHP ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

To set an array of checkboxes with PHP I use encoded decimals from a DB. For instance dec 5 (binary 0000 0101 sets `checkbox` 1 and 3 to `checked`.
I use a ternary operator as in this example for checkbox 1:

```
(5 & 1 == 1 ? 'checked' : '')
```

The result is `false`, though it should be `true`.

Only when I use additional parenthesis in the condition part `(5 & 1) == 1` do I get the correct result. Finally the example must look like this :

```
((5 & 1) == 1 ? 'checked' : '')
```

Does anyone know why you have to use parenthesis like this?

Comment: Look into [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: Well which do you mean? Do you mean to check for `1==1` first or if `5&1` first?

Comment: @ John Conde - Ok, so a ˚comparision˚ has a higher precedence than a ˚bitwise˚ operator, thanks. If you post an answer I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise AND operator `&` has a lower *precedence* than `==`. And the *ternary conditional* operator has the lowest precedence of the operators you're using.

So `5 & 1 == 1 ? 'checked' : ''` is evaluated as `(5 & (1 == 1)) ? 'checked' : ''`.

Your placing parentheses around `5 & 1` is the correct thing to do.